# How do I check the errorcode of a `&` Powershell command?

Tags: powershell

In a Powershell script, I run a command like:

```
& "C:\...\myprogram.exe"
```

How do I check to see if myprogram.exe returned an errorcode?

Comment: [`$LastExitCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#lastexitcode)

Comment: According to PowerShell, $LASTEXITCODE is all upper case. `Get-ChildItem -Path Variable: | Where-Object Name -eq 'lastexitcode'` Yes, I know that PowerShell is mostly case insensitive. Consistently using the initial definition reduces noise.

Comment: You can also use `[System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception]::new($LASTEXITCODE).Message` for a better description

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run it with the call operator (or without), check `$LASTEXITCODE`. It will always be the exit code of the last program you ran in the current session.

If you need to use `Start-Process` instead (such as needing to use `-Wait` to wait on a GUI application to complete), make sure to use `-PassThru` to store the process object as a variable, then check its `ExitCode` property. `$LASTEXITCODE` is not set in this case.